# enter arabic characters in database

Tags: mysql, database, jsf-2, utf-8, arabic

While creating database for my website I used below syntax.

```
CREATE DATABASE myDatabase DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Now while my client is entering **arabic characters**, he see some weird output. I am using JSF 2.0 for web pages.

What changes do I need to make so that I can enter Arabic or any characters in my site and it get stored in DB.

### Edit 1

While I am printing the data, I am seeing output as `Ø´Ø³Ù?Ø¨Ø´Ø³Ù? Ø¨Ø´Ø³Ù?Ø¨ Ø´Ø³Ù?Ø¨`

### Note:

I am using web application using JSF 2.0

Comment: First, is the data saved in the database correctly? Where are you seeing the output from?

Comment: @babooney : while reading the data, and print it using System.out.println I see output as `Ø´Ø³Ù?Ø¨Ø´Ø³Ù? Ø¨Ø´Ø³Ù?Ø¨ Ø´Ø³Ù?Ø¨`

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @SreenathSoman : how to check whether its UTF-8 or ANSI?

Comment: sorry its not ANSI, it is ISO-8859-1.. anyway which server are you using ?

Comment: @SreenathSoman : I am using hosting my site on from hosting site. I have Tomcat there...

Comment: check this: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q1

Comment: this would help you i think, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1125802/1600692

Comment: Someone else was having exactly the same problem today (your colleague or just a clone account of yourself?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451061/why-arabic-letters-are-not-inserting-in-database

Answer (score 1):

You should set UTF8 charset for the connection before the inserting/reading data -

```
SET NAMES utf8;
INSERT INTO table VALUES(...);

SELECT * FROM table;
```

Comment: I am using JSF 2.0. I did as you said, while I get exception as `java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD9?\xD8\xB4\xD8\xB4...' for column 'fullName' at row 1`

Answer (score 1):

Use N'' when you insert data values, This denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode (the N actually stands for National language character set)

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(N'ArabicField');
```

Comment: I am entering arabic text... not english text... please

Comment: Ok, `INSERT INTO table VALUES(N'نص عربي');`

Comment: it will be correct by default. i believe that your problem is while inserting.

Comment: [More info is here](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/foreign-languages-using-mysql-and-php.html) , Read the mySQL related part,

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use `cp1256_general_ci` instead of `utf8_general_ci`,
and don't forget to set the collation of the database and all fields that may contain Arabic words to `utf8_general_ci`.